# How to get the list of microservices endpoints from springboot projects stored in GitLab

Tags: python, spring-boot, gitlab, microservices, endpoint

I am managing multiple springboot projects in GitLab. Currently API endpoint is extracted manually by browsing through the code files in GitLab one by one to get the endpoint available for each project. Is there a way to get the list of microservices endpoints from all the projects through coding like python?

Example controller class:

@RestController
public class TestController {

```
@GetMapping("/testapi")
public String TestApi(){
    return "call to /testapi";
}
@PostMapping("/testapi2")
public String TestApi2(){
    return "call to /testapi2";
}
```

Expected result:

1. Endpoint-/testapi method-GET
2. Endpoint-/testapi2 method-POST

Answer (score 0):

Without deploying the services/projects I'm not sure there is an easy way to do this.

If you can deploy the services/projects an easy way to discover all endpoints is adding openapi/swagger to your project.

Here you can find what you need to add it to your spring boot application.
https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation